# is there a way to `ls` midway through the path of a `cp` or `mv` command (i.e. without cd-ing to the directory in order to perform an `ls`)?

Tags: ls, mv, cd-command

I'm looking for a more efficient way to check what directories and files exist midway through typing the path for a `cp` or `mv` command without having to cd to the folder and running `ls`, then returning to my `cp` or `mv` command.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about tab completion...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try hitting the tab key; once to attempt to complete whichever file or directory name you've begun to type or twice to display the files or directories you might type at any point in your "cp" or "mv" command.

Comment: I needed to hit tab twice, but yes this is what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that.  I've corrected my answer.